# Should this question have been moved to Superuser.com instead of deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889293/does-linux-generate-more-heat-than-window-on-laptops/11890303#11890303

Unfortunately since it's been deleted you'll need a lot of rep to see it.

I should add that although the user seemed intent on reasking the question there, looking at their history it never happened.

Comment: Speaking as an SU mod, when an SO user asks "should we migrate this to SU instead of deleting it," the answer is very, very rarely "yes".

Comment: @nhinkle I can't see if the OP ever asked that question on SU. Did he? if so, was it deleted?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yes, [here](http://superuser.com/questions/459649/does-linux-generate-more-heat-than-windows-on-laptops). Closed on August 12, deleted on September 20.

Comment: @AnnaLear, thanks - I don't have the rep on SU to see deleted questions.

Comment: You know, there are times when I've disagreed with moderator decisions to delete content. This? This is not one of them. This question is crap and it deserves to be culled as such.

Comment: We appear to have a consensus. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is literally: "Yes, Windows is cooler than linux?"

The question has... *99 problems and deletion isn't one*:

- **Not constructive**: "Does Windows run cooler than linux?" Person A: "Yes." Person B: "No." Who's right?
- **Too Localized**: This could very well be dependent upon hardware issues with that particular person. It could be a defective part. It could be a lot of things, But without something more definitive than "My laptop is hot when I run Linux." There's no way to say how to fix the problem (see the first problem, above)
- **Flamebait**.

To improve the question, the OP could:

- **Give us metrics**. Run some benchmarks, run them multiple times, collect data.
- **Give us some specs**.  Right now it's Lenovo Ideapad Y580. Is it the stock version? Upgrades of any kind? Anything aftermarket?

With those improvements, I think it should be moved to Superuser, but we're not in the habit of migrating crap, so it's unlikely it'd be moved before then.

If the post is improved and flagged, we'll take a look at it then.

The OP has literally had from August 9th (the day it was closed) until today to improve the question.  They have not done so.

Comment: Would also depend on load, and *what* he's running I'd guess too.

Comment: It's an old question, so unlikely to be updated, but thanks for your input. I had heard of this problem from other sources though, so I don't think it's really too localized.

Comment: @MarkRansom It all comes down to data and specs. Without it, there could be 100 causes.

Comment: I have a different viewpoint - if someone else has the same question, are they going to find useful information in the answers? Hard data isn't a requirement in that circumstance.

Comment: Hi Mark, if the person asked "What causes this" or "What can I do to fix it" then the answers would be more useful. But simply polling the community and seeing if there are other people feeling the pain doesn't help. That's the extent of the question in the post body. *Do YOU have this problem too?*. After all, Stack Exchange isn't a support group. ;)  All joking aside, the question could be fixed with some edits by the asker, if he/she focuses on describing the problem thoroughly and focusing on solutions. :)  I also note that both answers are speculating...

Comment: Not saying the deletion was unjustified, but why would a defective part and/or other hardware issues affect Linux but not Windows? FWIW, my laptop *does* get measurably hotter under Ubuntu than Windows 7 when performing similar tasks (mostly browsing the web). When I boot my Hackintosh, it's even worse.